# Get the currently allowed scopes of an OAuth user

Tags: github, github-api

I would like to know how to get a currently allowed scopes for a user signed in with GitHub.

Currently, I am maintaining a local copy of the authorized scopes, but I think it might be better to get the *real* data to avoid possible inconsistencies.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all [your personal access token](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#list-your-authorizations) or if you know the current ID of the access token you're looking for you can [retrieve it individually](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#get-a-single-authorization).

This is the sample response for a single token. You are interested in the `scopes` element:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "url": "https://api.github.com/authorizations/1",
  "scopes": [
    "public_repo"
  ],
  "token": "",
  "token_last_eight": "12345678",
  "hashed_token": "25f94a2a5c7fbaf499c665bc73d67c1c87e496da8985131633ee0a95819db2e8",
  "app": {
    "url": "http://my-github-app.com",
    "name": "my github app",
    "client_id": "abcde12345fghij67890"
  },
  "note": "optional note",
  "note_url": "http://optional/note/url",
  "updated_at": "2011-09-06T20:39:23Z",
  "created_at": "2011-09-06T17:26:27Z",
  "fingerprint": "jklmnop12345678"
}
```